# If a function is locally Lipschitz, does its Fourier series converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function that is Riemann integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Suppose $f$ is locally Lipschitz. That is, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ and $M < \infty$ such that $|f(x+t)-f(x)| \leq M|t|$ for all $t \in (-\delta,\delta)$. Then does the Fourier series of $f$ converge to $f$ uniformly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally Lipschitz implies Lipschitz by compactness of $[-\pi, \pi]$. Hence the Fourier series converges uniformly.

Comment: Thank you, and what if we look at a non-compact set like $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: To clarify, suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and is locally Lipschitz for every point in $\mathbb{R}$. Then will the Fourier series converge uniformly?

Comment: Ah, OK, nevermind, I'm confusing things. It doesn't matter because $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic

Comment: Sir @KaviRamaMurthy where can I find a proof of this fact ? Or may be some hint will be nice.